# Bootstrap multi select search is very slow if pick list values are 9000

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, browser-cache, bootstrap-multiselect, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using below code jquery snippet for JQuery multiselect plugin based on Twitter Bootstrap. ( http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ )

Search results while filtering are loading very slow in all browsers ..
there are 9000 values in list now ,

### Could you please suggest me a way to get faster results for my search operation in bootstrap multi select .

$('#pid').multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableFullValueFiltering:true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    maxHeight: 200,
    buttonWidth: '225px',
    buttonText: function(options, select) {
        if (options.length === 0) {
            return '-Select-';
        } else {
            var labels = [];
            options.each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr('label') !== undefined) {
                    labels.push($(this).attr('label'));
                }
                else {
                    labels.push($(this).html());
                }
            });
            return labels.join(',') + '';
        }
    }

### });

Comment: You're going to run into this problem with any list that long. For that many results you really ought to be filtering out only a subset of options based on user input.

Comment: 9000 possible values to me suggests the need for an autocomplete + multiselect solution.

Comment: My Requirement is for 'Multi select Pick list' so i have used above library which helps exactly what i need but the performance is very bad for such huge pick list size . I am trying for auto complete + multi select but failed to do so .